# Fetch data from URL in r

Tags: html, r, web

i want to fetch details from this URL (lines containing "exon")

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002117.5
```

i tried using the following commands:-

```
url <- "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002117.5"    
resp <- GET(url)    
content(resp)
```

however, i am not able to access the data.

Comment: What are you trying to access? The code in your example works as expected (with the addition of `library(httr)`).

Comment: I already loaded the library before running the code. The data that it is fetching does not appear correct. It doesnot print the content of the web page, rather gives some extra information that doesnot connect to my query @neilfws

Comment: Maybe describe what you *are* seeing, rather than what you're *not* seeing. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Response [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002117.5]
  Date: 2017-05-30 05:24
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 121 kB
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"><meta ht...
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow,noarchive" />
<meta name="ncbi_app" content="entrez" /><meta name="ncbi_db"...

    
    <!-- title -->
...

Comment: This is what is printed when I run the command **content(resp)**

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I want to access the **data/content** present in the aforementioned link. but this is what I am getting

Comment: That is what you should expect to see; a truncated summary of the XHTML content. The next step is to figure out how to parse and extract the parts that you want.

Comment: @neilfws **content(resp)** actually parse the data but in my case it is not doing it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a look at the file, itself, you can always download it:

```
fileUrl <- "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002117.5"
download.file(fileUrl, "./NM_002117.5", method="curl")
```

I think that method="curl" is only required in macOS. This way, you can open file in text editor. Is that what you were referring to while saying that you are not able to access data?

In fact you have your data, in R, but they are HTML content.

Comment: i tried this also    url <-"https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_002117.5"    destfile <- "myfile1.txt"    
download.file(url, destfile) . Still the file doesnot have all the required information

Comment: In that case, question is. What does "all the required information" mean in context of the question. What happens if you open that file in browser? Does it contain data you are looking for?

Comment: @mk0 yes if I open the link in the browser it shows texts, whereas when I do download.file it contains the majority of URLs

Comment: Well, it should be like that. After all, this is HTML. What you need to do, is to parse HTML file. If you take a look at the file, you should spot something like this <pre class="genbank">...</pre>. Text between <pre> tags are you data, I think.